# How to automatically update CMake files in jucipp?

Tags: c++, ide

So, jucipp is a pretty cool IDE but I'm not sure how to add files to my project. I certainly don't want to be managing my own CMake files.

Does anybody have any experience with this IDE and knows how to automate the build process?

Answer (score 0):

Well, historically, CMake was able to generate projects files for IDEs (Code::Blocks, Eclipse, Visual Studio), but now things are shifting towards IDEs being able to run CMake and parse CMakeLists.txt files themselves.

See this talk by Stephen Kelly at FOSDEM 2016 for instance https://fosdem.org/2016/schedule/event/cmake_gui/attachments/slides/1149/export/events/attachments/cmake_gui/slides/1149/cmake_gui_tools.pdf

So it's seem you're going to need to learn how to write CMakeLists files, sorry :)

Comment: Ah, I see. That's lame. Thanks for the reply though! I thought jucipp might be too indie for a second.